# Adding "libusb.h" search path to Xcode 5 (OS X v10.9 (Mavericks))

Tags: c++, macos, xcode5, osx-mavericks, libusb

I am trying to get the Kinect library "libfreenect" to work on OS X v10.9 (Mavericks). It always ends in "device not found". So I thought I could test *libusb* with Xcode to see what USB devices are recognised.

I am using sample code from *[Introduction To Using LibUSB-1.0](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148707-introduction-to-using-libusb-10/)*

Xcode project settings are:

- OS X -> Application -> Command Line Tool
- C++

When trying to compile, Xcode complains:

```
/.../libusb-Test/libusb-Test/main.cpp:2:10: 'libusb.h' file not found
```

I tried several things to fix the issue:

1. Adding "/opt/local/include" to: Preferences -> Locations
2. Adding "/opt/local/include/libusb-1.0" to: Preferences -> Locations
3. Adding "/opt/local/include/libusb-1.0" to: Build Settings -> Library Search Path

[IMAGE: Xcode, Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcSbK.png)

The only thing that seems to work is:

```
#include </opt/local/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
```

But that doesn't seem to be the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Include files are not libraries. You need to adjust "header search path", not "library search path".

Comment: thanks for the hint :) don't know why this is down voted :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you verify that the "Always Search User Paths" Build Setting is set to YES. Then you might add a User Header Search Path that includes the directory holding your reference.

[image: paths]